# Tell me a bit about Telegram API things such as: Chat ID, User ID

Tags: bots, telegram

I have a bot for Telegram. It's functionality is very simple. All I need is bot sending me all messages, that people send to him.

But to send messages exactly to me, Chat ID is needed. I got it, but the question is following: Is this Chat ID - unique and constant value, that belongs exactly to my Telegram Account or no, and if not, what is actually Chat ID and how does it work.

Also I found that I can get sender's User ID. Can I send messages from Bot using not Chat ID, but User ID, that is also easy to get?

By the way, I'm using [Java SDK](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots). Thank you.

I tried getting my own account's Chat ID by adding a function to bot: send to the sender it's Chat ID. Code will be shown below. It works, but I am not sure it's correct.

```
if (!update.getMessage().isCommand()) {
    String senderId;
    User sender = update.getMessage().getFrom();
    String messageText = update.getMessage().getText();
    if(update.getMessage().getFrom().getUserName() != null) {
        senderId = "@" + sender.getUserName();
    } else {
        senderId = sender.getFirstName() + " " + sender.getLastName();
    }
    Long arthurChat = 100000001L;
    sendMessage(arthurChat, "Message: " + messageText + "\n" + "Sender: " + senderId);
}
```

Waiting for reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Chat.id` uniquely identify a chat, while `User.id` uniquely identify a user.

In a private chat those two values coincide, so you can get that information in both following ways, while in a group chat only the first one will give you the actual sender id, while the second one will give you the id of the group

```
update.getMessage().getFrom().getId();
update.getMessage().getChat().getId();
```

In the snippet that you reported you are using a method called `sendMessage()` but it is deprecated in rubenlagus' java library that you are using. Instead you should do as follows:

```
SendMessage replyMessage = new SendMessage()
            .setChatId(arthurChat)
            .setText(whateverTextYouWantToSend);
execute(replyMessage);
```